# WordPress/WooCommerce - Remove html data prepended to a returned json data

Tags: php, json, wordpress, woocommerce

I don't have access to my customers' PC to check what's happening there. But I have a WordPress plugin that is installed there. The problem is, it returned an extra `<style>...<style>` prepended to json data.

This problem is only happening in one of my customer's system and not the others. It seems there is a hook that prepends some styles to some products (I said **some**, because some other products don't return that extra `<style>...</style>`) and when it wants to return the json data, it returns the `<style>...</style>` too like so:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .product {
        ...
    }
    ...
    ...
</style>
[{"version":"1.0.0","data":"..."}]
```

The data are being fetched in an array like this:

```
$products = array(
    'id' => $product_id,
    'regular_price' => $product->get_regular_price(),
    'sale_price' => $product->get_sale_price(),
);

exit(json_encode($products));
```

But it seems the problem is not from these parameters because it doesn't return that extra style when I get only these parameters. I think it returns that extra style when I use one of these functions:

`wp_get_post_terms`, `$product_variations->get_available_variations()`

aren't they the issues?

So what I've done is removing anything before returning the json data like so:

```
ob_start(function () { return ''; });
@ob_end_clean();
http_response_code(200);
exit(json_encode($data));
```

I have also set the `content-type` and `accept` to `application/json`.

How can I remove those extra data?

Comment: If its only happening to one WP install then the problem is somewhere there. Can your client turn off any other plugins and leave only the required ones? If that doesnt solve it can your client also change a theme for testing ? These stuff should be done on dev enviroment not on live website at first place. Remote debug is pain in the ass so i would insist on some access if my client wants me to fix it.

Comment: I told him, and he said he would fix it as he had used some hooks in an inappropriate way. Thanks